# Creating an index in a temporary tablespace

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create an index for a relatively large table (80M rows).

First I got an **ORA-01652** error, then I searched in SO and found [a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098069/creating-an-extremely-large-index-in-oracle)

However, trying to implement the steps mentioned there,I got an **ORA-02195**: *Attempt to create PERMANENT object in a TEMPORARY tablespace* error.

If index is a permanent object and cannot be created in a temporary tablespace, how should I understand [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#i1006643) part of Oracle manual?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables and indexes are created in users tablespace, which is `USERS` by default. A temporary tablespace, `TEMP` by default, is used by oracle for sorting large amount of data on disk. Temporary tablespace is typically used for processing joins, order by or creating indexes.

Since the default tablespace `TEMP` is not large enough for creating a large index, your example creates a large temporary tablespace `ts_tmp` for the index creation purpose only and drops it afterwards.

When creating the index with `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... TABLESPACE ...` command, don't use `ts_tmp`  in the `TABLESPACE` clause. This will give you `Attempt to create PERMANENT object in a TEMPORARY tablespace error`.

Either don't use the `TABLESPACE` clause, then the defualt users tablespace will be used. Or give a tablespace name that was created with a `CREATE TABLESPACE` command.

Comment: So I won't create a temporary tablespace but a permanent tablespace with `CREATE TABLESPACE` command. I wasn't using `TABLESPACE` clause while creating index anyway. But still I wonder why Oracle (and the answer to the question linked above) tells to use temporary tablespace and then drop it after creating index.

Comment: You will create the temporay tablespace, but you won't use it to create the index. It will be used by oracle while creating the index. If you were not using the `TABLESPACE` clause with the `CREATE INDEX` command, did you by any chance use `ALTER USER me DEFAULT TABLESPACE ts_tmp` command by mistake intead of `ALTER USER me TEMPORARY TABLESPACE ts_tmp`?

Comment: I used `ALTER USER MY_USERNAME TEMPORARY TABLESPACE ts_tmp` . Thanks for answering by the way.

Comment: Did you replace `me` with your username in the commands?